# $firebaseArray is empty with ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to load data in firebase with `$firebaseArray` as:

```js
var ref = new Firebase(FURL);
var eventRef = ref.child('event');
$scope.events= $firebaseArray(eventRef)
```

I have `event` data in my firebase. But my `$scope.events` returns:

```
[]
  0: Object
  $$added: ()
  $$error: ()
  $$getKey: ()
  $$moved: ()
  $$notify: ()
  $$process: ()
  $$removed: ()
  $$updated: ()
  $add: ()
  $destroy: ()
  $getRecord: ()
  $indexFor: ()
  $keyAt: ()
  $loaded: ()
  $ref: ()
  $remove: ()
  $save: ()
  $watch: ()
  length: 0__proto__: Array[0]
```

what is possible reason?

Comment: What you're showing there is the in-memory representation on a `$firebaseArray`. The code looks fine, the output looks fine.

Comment: This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34932687/how-to-navigate-object-returned-from-angularfire/34933002#34933002

Answer (score 1):

**Possible Reason** You are accessing data before it is is loaded.

You must wait till data is loaded, Rewrite your code this way:

```
var ref = new Firebase(FURL);
var eventRef = ref.child('event');
$scope.events = $firebaseArray(eventRef);

$scope.events.$loaded()
    .then(function(){
        // access events here;
    });
```

Comment: Keep in mind `$loaded()` will only be triggered when the *initial* data has loaded. Since `$firebaseArray` *synchronizes* changes from the server, most operations should *not* be done in response to `$loaded()`.

Comment: That depends on what the operation is that you do in `$loaded`, which unfortunately neither you nor the question say anything about. A common usage is that people count the number of items in the array and add that to the DOM. If you do that with `$loaded()`, you will only be showing the *initial* count. For that type of use-case, you should be [extending `$firebaseArray`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/extending-services.html#section-firebasearray). If you just want to log the events to see that loading works, put this in your HTML: `<pre>{{ events | json }}</pre>`

Comment: Thanks for explanation :) I have been developing for more than a year in firebase, I am still firebase student and still learning how to answer as best as you do.

Comment: You're doing great. Keep up the good work and thanks for helping others learn about Firebase too!

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon while you are correct, here's some more information as to why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34932687/how-to-navigate-object-returned-from-angularfire/34933002#34933002